# Remove cached password for Git on Windows

Tags: git, caching, passwords, reset, unset

I have recently updated my Github password at work (corporate Github account). I had configured Git on one of my VM which is Windows 10. Not whenever I do `git pull` or `git push` it throws error message:

`remote: Invalid username and password
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://<my_project_repository>'`

I tried many of the options available online but none of them is helping which can bring the username/password prompt back. I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling it but it didn't help either.

I am not using Git GUI. Using it through Git bash only.

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git

Answer (score 26):

I have encountered the same issue. Reinstalling won't solve it. You will have to update it in your Credential Manager. Go to Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager > Windows Credentials. You will see Git credentials in the list (e.g. git:https://). Click on it, update the password, and execute git pull/push command from your Git bash and it it won't throw any error message.

Comment: how did you figure this out? The official docs don't have this information as far as I checked.